# Relentless hex and invisible target

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, invisibility, eldritch-invocations, hexblade

If you Hexblade Cursed a target and you have Relentless Hex as an Eldritch Invocation, what happens when your target goes invisible, but remains within 30 feet of you?

The description of Relentless Hex says you are teleporting to a space you can see, within 5 feet of the target, but says nothing about whether you need to see the target. Are you able to do so?

Comment: Welcome to the stack MewMew, take the [tour] when you have a moment. This is a great question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### You must be able to see the cursed target.

From Xanathar's Guide to Everthing p.57:

> ##### Relentless Hex
>
> *Prerequisite: 7th level, hex spell or a warlock feature that curses*
>
> Your curse creates a temporary bond between you and your target. As a bonus action, you can magically teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see within 5 feet of the target cursed by your hex spell or by a warlock feature of yours, such as Hexblade's Curse or Sign of Ill Omen. **To teleport in this way, you must be able to see the cursed target.**

Comment: Well now I feel silly. Indeed it is there. Thank you!

Comment: Although that important bit is missing in the overview version of invocation in DndBeyond's charactersheet. Which is what most players see during play (if they are using the tool). Hence the confusion

Answer (score 8):

### You must be able to see the target

The text of the Relentless Hex ability actually has as the last line:

> To teleport in this way, you must be able to see the cursed target.

This is consistent on D&D Beyond both in the [Warlock class page](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) and the [compendium version of *XGtE*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/subclasses#RelentlessHex), as well as in the copy of *XGtE* I have access to, though I'm not sure what print run it is. It is not mentioned as an errata change in the most recent [errata for *XGtE*](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/XGtE-Errata.pdf), so it was probably also included even in the original printing of the text (though WotC is not above making meaningful text changes without noting them in the errata - so-called "stealth errata" by the community - so I can't guarantee it was always printed so).

If the version of the text you have access to doesn't include that stipulation, it is either outdated or an inaccurate reproduction of the ability.